# Move file between my PC and Laptop

Tags: windows, file-transfer

I have a 2GB file I need to move from my PC to my Laptop.

I have no USB drive available, I don't have WiFi on my laptop, however I do have a small windows server in my house sitting right next to my Desktop.  Is there any way, without a USB Drive or WiFi, for me to move this file? I can use the server

Comment: Copy/move the file from the PC to a "public" folder on the server, then copy/move it from the folder to the laptop?

Comment: Am I able to connect to the server without WiFi?

Comment: If your laptop is not one of the newest ultrathins with no ethernet port, you can connect your laptop using an ethernet cable, just like the desktop.

Comment: If your laptop has _no_ network connectivity, then you're going to be out of luck - but with no connectivity, what good is the laptop in the first place?

Comment: Presumably "no wifi" means there is no wifi router available

Comment: I'm looking to do this remotely, so an ethernet cable wouldn't be ideal. Also yes, there's no WiFi router available

Comment: @Jon - When you indicate remotely what do you mean exactly?  Do you mean you are unable to make any hardware configuration changes?  Your question as it is currently written is not clear.  If the laptop has no ethernet port, and you have no access point, then you need to use an external storage device (CD,DVD,flash drive) no other way around that fact.

Comment: windows 10 fall creators update, will have computers close to eachother, with exchanging temporary passwords, to do so.  I forget what hardware or protocol though